# Direct object initialization vs Initialization with convertion functions

Tags: c++, class, c++11

The following program prints 42:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    operator int(){ return 42; }
};

struct B
{
    operator A(){ return A(); }
};

B b;
int a = A(b);    
int main(){ std::cout << a << std::endl; } //42
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f86b35ce40a1d132)**

But if we try to define cope/move or both contructors it won't work.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A(A&&){ std::cout << "A(A&&)" << std::endl; }
    A(A&){ std::cout << "A(A&)" << std::endl; }
    operator int(){ return 42; }
};

struct B
{
    operator A(){ return A(); }
};

B b;
int a = A(b);

int main(){ std::cout << a << std::endl; } //Error
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3440e6e95a138b1)**

I thought, the relevant section, describing that behavior is `N4296::8.5/17.7 [dcl.init]`

> If the destination type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type:
>
> [...]
>
> — Otherwise, if the source type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type, conversion functions are considered. The applicable conversion
>   functions are enumerated (13.3.1.5), and the best one is chosen
>   through overload resolution (13.3). The user-defined conversion so
>   selected is called to convert the  initializer expression into the
>   object being initialized. If the conversion cannot be done or is
>   ambiguous, the initialization is ill-formed.

It shouldn't depends on absence/presence of the constructors. We just should have to have appropriate conversion functions so as to choose the conversion sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You effectively deleted the default constructor. From the standard (12.1/4, emphasis mine):

> A *default* constructor for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X` that can be called without an argument. **If
>   there is no user-declared constructor for class `X`**, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared
>   as defaulted

**IF** there is no user-declared constructor. But you declared two, so there is no implicit default constructor. Thus, this:

```
operator A(){ return A(); }
                  // ^^^
```

can't compile. That's why the error you get is

> error: no matching function for call to `A::A()`

The code tries to call your conversion operator - but the body isn't valid.

Comment: Additionally if you have only `A::A(A&)` constructor and not `A::A(A&&)` constructor compilation would still fail (after adding `A::A()` constructor) because your `B::operator A()` returns non-const rvalue and `A&` reference cannot be bound to it. Important think is to have `A` constructor that would accept rvalue, eg. `A::A(A&&)` or `A::A(const A&)`